# Java acess the first list in a list of list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, nested

Here is my program

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> matrix = new ArrayList();  // nested list so as to have each matrix.add(new ArrayList());
matrix.add(new ArrayList());
matrix.add(new ArrayList());
```

I know I can access each item of the list by using matrix.get(0)
but what if I want to access the first item of the first nested list (I hope it is clear)
That is what I would like to do. 
It would even be better if I could turn each of the nested list or even the entire list into a proper array with nested arrays inside but that may be a tall order.
I am sorry my programming skills are really poor.

Comment: What about `matrix.get(0).get(0)`?

Comment: Why is `matrix.get(0).get(0)` bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the first item of the first list you could do `matrix.get(0).get(0);`. When you do `matrix.get(0)` that returns the first `List`, which you can then do more operations on (`get`, `add`, `remove`, etc.) which is no different then something like `aList.get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?> foo = matrix.get(0).get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to refer to the first element of the first element

```
matrix.get(0).get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(1);
    matrix.add(al);
    ArrayList<Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al2.add(2);
    al2.add(3);
    matrix.add(al2);

    Object[] objs = new Object[al.size()];
    objs = matrix.toArray(objs);
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(objs));
}
```

Outputs

```
[[1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, following code describes everything for you:

```
//get the first list from matrix
List<?> firstNestedList = matrix.get(0);

//get the first element from the firstNestedList 
Object neededElement = firstNestedList.get(0);
```